# Caching in Jersey client based on last modified http header?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I have a web service that uses last modified http header to provide caching support.The server side method is as below.The problem is that on client side do i have to store the last modified times for each id in a map.I see that modern browsers send the last modified header.Isn't there something in the client framework to achieve the same ?

//server side code

```
          @Path("/resource/{id}")
          @GET
          @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          public Response getResource(@PathParam("id") int id){
         Date lastModified=service.getLastModified(id);
         ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(lastModified);
            if (responseBuilder != null) {
              return responseBuilder.build();
            }
          SomeResource someResource=service.getResource(id);
        return Response.ok(someResource).lastModified(lastModified).build();
   }
```

**//client side--how do i set the lastmodified date?**
Do i maintain a id-->date map?

```
String path="/resource/1234"
final Response res = target(path).request().header("if-Modified-Since", lastmodified).get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Jersey has such a feature. If you want to mimic the browser caching, you can see how [RESTeasy implements it](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/cache), with its client caching feature. Everything is self contained in that package I linked to (except for a couple util classes). It's basically just implemented using client filters to cache the request/response info, so you don't need to add those those headers yourself.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?